# Issue to reference in shared project in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, json.net, cross-platform

I have just create a cross platform application in Xamarin. I created one function in a shared project in which it deserializes the JSON string into object/s but there is no way to add reference for Newtonsoft .

how can i use the reference in shared project ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using VS just click on **tool**-> **Nuget package manager** -> Manage **Nuget package for solution** and Install **Newtonsoft.json** after select all the platform in checkbox.

Now you can use it in your share project also.

Comment: sorry but while adding nuget package extension it will not shown shared project to add extension in that.

Comment: thanks now it will access after apply into all projects. Thanks @Ashish

Answer (score 2):

In a shared project you'll use the references that are in the Android or iOS project. Thats why it's a shared project. Just add the refrence from nuget to your Android and iOS project and you should be good.

For more information: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/shared_projects/